Шаблон для visual studio 2022. Изменить свой шаблон что бы подставлялись свои переменные
При создании кода по шаблону, что бы подставлялись свою переменные. Ссылка на документацию
Создаю свой шаблон нужно из названия класса вырезать часть слова и подставить в нужные места.
Есть такая конструкция $if$ ($var tt = $safeitemname$.Replace("ControllerTest",""); tt$)222; $endif$111; Но она выводит только 111. Если возможность обрезать название класса и использовать как переменную?

не буду говорить от лица всех, но мне кажется вопрос стоит переформулировать. Я перечитал раз 3 и я всё ещё не смог понять его суть

Существуют шаблоны для кода. Они вызываются при создании классов, интерфейсов итд итп. Нужно в своем шаблоне подменить переменную $safeitemname$ на свою по коду расставлены метки.

Нужно использовать IWizard это отдельное приложение, которое будет изменять код на лету примеры тут или в документации
